# Import a CSV file into Access using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, csv, ms-access

I need to use VBA to import a large CSV excel file into an Access table. The delimiter is "" (double quotes) except for some reason the first value is followed by " (only one quote) instead of two like every other value. The first row contains the column headers and are delimited the same way. At the bottom I have attached an example.

The CSV files are generated automatically by an accounting system daily so I cannot change the format. They are also quite large (150,000+ lines, many columns). I'm fairly new to VBA, so as much detail as is possible would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

[Example of format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkUi5.png)

Comment: So they're not CSV files then?  It would be helpful to show a sample of the type of content you're dealing with (make something up if you can't share actual content)

Comment: Probably real delimiter is invisible, string values enclosed in double quotes. In order to understand what is real delimiter, it would be great to see hex dump of 2-3 values

Comment: @TimWilliams I edited the post and added a link to an example picture of what it looks like

Comment: @sergey I edited the post and added a link to an example picture of what it looks like

Comment: If you open the file in a text editor (eg. notepad) does it look the same ?

Comment: Yes, I understood how it looks in Excel or Notepad, but my point was to figure out if file has not-printable (invisible) characters between double quotes, which should be used as data separator, file hex dump needed for this . Can you give a link to data sample?

Comment: @tim when I open it in notepad, every value and header is surrounded by quotes and there is a tab between each value as well.

Comment: @sergey I cannot provide any of the data, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't sound like a CSV file.  Can you open it in Excel, convert it to a true CSV, and then import that into Access?  You will find many VBA-driven import options at the URL below.

http://www.accessmvp.com/KDSnell/EXCEL_Import.htm

Also, take a look at these URLs.

http://www.erlandsendata.no/english/index.php?d=envbadacimportado

http://www.erlandsendata.no/english/index.php?d=envbadacimportdao